# Building rpm - File not found by glob:

Tags: linux, makefile, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to generate an rpm package (Redhat) ,I get an error when i launched the command : `rpmbuild -ba librabbitmq.spec`

> Processing files: librabbitmq1-0.10.0-0.x86_64 error: File not found
> by glob:
> /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/librabbitmq-0.10.0-0.x86_64/usr/local/lib64/librabbitmq.so.1*
>
> RPM build errors:
> File not found by glob: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/librabbitmq-0.10.0-0.x86_64/usr/local/lib64/librabbitmq.so.1*

How can correct the command install in the Makefile ? Any suggestions please .

MAKEFILE:

```
#Build a static library
NAME= librabbitmq.so
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -g -DHAVE_POLL -DHAVE_SELECT -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
    
OBJDIR := obj
#definition des fichiers headers
INCLUDES := -I/usr/local/include/ -I/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/librabbitmq-0.10.0 -I/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/librabbitmq-0.10.0/unix
#definition des librairies
LFLAGS := -L/usr/local/lib64
LDFLAGS :=
LIBS := -L. -lpopt
SRCS_RAW := amqp_api.c amqp_connection.c amqp_consumer.c amqp_framing.c amqp_hostcheck.c amqp_mem.c amqp_openssl_bio.c amqp_openssl.c \
amqp_openssl_hostname_validation.c amqp_socket.c amqp_table.c amqp_tcp_socket.c amqp_time.c amqp_url.c 


OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW:.c=.o))

.PHONY: all
all: $(NAME)
    @echo "$(MAKE) : Tout est genere"

$(NAME):$(OBJS)
    ar rcs $(NAME) $(OBJS) 
    ranlib $(NAME)

#règle pour créer un répertoire d'objets s'il n'existe pas
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

#définir une règle implicite pour créer des objets dans leur propre répertoire
#(note - ordre uniquement la dépendance sur le répertoire d'objets)
# $<:premier_dependance $@:cible 
$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@ 
    
prefix:=/usr/local
install: librabbitmq.so
    install -m 644 librabbitmq.so $(prefix)/lib64
.PHONY: install

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *~  $(NAME)
    $(RM) -r  $(OBJDIR)
```

SPEC FILE:

```
#
# spec file for package librabbitmq
#

%global sover   1
%global libname %{name}%{sover}
Name:           librabbitmq
Version:        0.10.0
Release:        0
Summary:        Amqp library in C
Source:         librabbitmq-0.10.0.tar.xz
# Some internal tests are licenced as GPL-3.0+ - they are only used in
# check phase and not shipped further
License:        LGPL-2.1-or-later
Group:          Development/Libraries/C and C++
Url:            https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c

%description
This is a C-language AMQP client library for use with v2.0+ of the RabbitMQ broker.


%package -n %{libname}
Summary:        Amqp library written in C
License:        LGPL-2.1-or-later
Group:          System/Libraries

%define _prefix   /usr/local
#%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0

%description -n %{libname}
Shared library for %{name} (%{summary}).

%package devel
Summary:        Amqp library written in C
License:        LGPL-2.1-or-later
Group:          Development/Libraries/C and C++
Requires:       %{libname} = %{version}
Requires:       pkgconfig

%description devel
Headers, pkg-config files, so link and other development files for %{name}
(%{summary}).

%prep
%setup -q

%build
make 

%install
%make_install

%check

%post -n %{libname} -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun -n %{libname} -p /sbin/ldconfig

%files -n %{libname}
%{_libdir}/%{name}.so.%{sover}*

%files devel
%doc CHANGELOG.md
%{_includedir}/rabbitmq.h
%{_libdir}/%{name}.so


%changelog
```

Comment: Correct and useless answer would be: you need to make the `librabbitmq` provide this file. The thing to do here is to ask the package maintainer, or someone who knows how to build it, for help. The question needs a research and there's not enough information to answer here.

Answer (score 2):

**DON'T BUILD RPMS AS ROOT.**

That said, your `Makefile` is bad, and you've now overwritten files all over your computer. Which is *why* you shouldn't build RPMs as root.

The `Makefile` needs to support the GNU-standard `DESTDIR` variable when calling `make install`. It likely has other problems, I didn't look much further than a search for the most common mistake.